# Function component method spyOn failing unittest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am using function component where is there is a arrow function.

```
const handleOnConfig = (cfg) => {
  const layout = { ...config };
  setConfig(layout);
};
```

Now, I want to write unit test for that function.

So, I did following in my test file. I used

```
beforeEach(() => {
  let props = {user:user}
   view = shallow(<Views {...props} />).instance();
});
test('should call config change call back', () => {
    const handleOnConfig = jest.spyOn(view,'handleOnConfig').mockImplementation(() => config);
    expect(handleOnConfig).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

But, this test case gives error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleOnConfig' of null

Any help would greatly appreciated

**Edit:**

Views component

```
const Views = forwardRef(({ user, id }, ref) => {

useEffect(() => {
    handleOnConfig();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
        <Component 
          user={user}
          id={id}
          name='Component' 
        />
    </div>
  );

})

export default Views;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem with `spyOn()` directly: your `view` variable is `null`.

Try using [`.dive()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) in the return from `shadow()`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  let props = {user:user}
  view = shallow(<Views {...props} />).dive().instance(); // <-- added .dive()
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but It gives error:  TypeError: ShallowWrapper::dive() can not be called on Host Components

Comment: Can you show the content of `Views`?

Comment: Sorry, thought replied you. I edited question in same day. You can check